# devtodev NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getGooglePlayInstantParam()Z

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

After adding the facebook sdk to the project, I saw these logs.

> 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL
> EXCEPTION: pool-14-thread-1 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error
> AndroidRuntime Process: com.HobbEduapp, PID: 11015 2023/10/05
> 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> getGooglePlayInstantParam()Z in class
> Lcom/android/installreferrer/api/ReferrerDetails; or its super classes
> (declaration of 'com.android.installreferrer.api.ReferrerDetails'
> appears in /data/app/com.HobbEduapp-2dL4LPZCg9qYT606P7XEdA==/base.apk)
> 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime  at
> com.devtodev.analytics.internal.platform.repository.playservice.h$b$b.invoke(ReferrerClient.kt:39)
> 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime  at
> com.devtodev.analytics.internal.queue.QueueManager$Companion.d(QueueManager.kt:1)
> 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime  at
> com.devtodev.analytics.internal.queue.-$$Lambda$ZAjvo-fi54tKNKnlwmGwSbmlW8g.run(Unknown
> Source:2) 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> 2023/10/05 23:04:25.705 11015 11329 Error AndroidRuntime  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

I changed versions of Facebook SDK. I also changed the DTD versions

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the DevToDev team for help;

It looks like you are missing a Google Play Install Refferer dependency.
Please add the dependency

```
'< androidPackage spec=“com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2” />'
```

into the file \Assets\DevToDev\Analytics\Editor\AppDependencies.xml.
Also please add to proguard.txt the following (more about proguard here):

```
-keep class com.devtodev.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.devtodev.**
```